# Python variable not registering with if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

When I ask the user if they would like to mega size their order, python says that it is a invalid entry. Dont mind the choice[] list, it is used elsewhere.

```
  print("What size would you like?\nSmall ($1.50)\nMedium ($2.50)\nLarge ($3.50)\n")
  main_choice=input("-").lower()
  if main_choice=="small":
    choice.append("small")
    money+=1.50
    pass
  elif main_choice=="medium":
    choice.append("medium")
    money+=2.50
    pass
  elif main_choice=="large":
    choice.append("large")
    money+=3.50
    os.system('clear')
    t.sleep(1)
    print("Would you like to Mega-Size your order for an extra $0.50? (yes/no)")
    main_choice=input("-").lower
    os.system('clear')
    if main_choice=="yes":
      money+=0.50
      choice[2]="Mega-Size"
      pass
    elif main_choice=="no":
      pass
    else:
      os.system('clear')
      print(Fore.RED+"That is a invalid entry please try again.")
      print(Style.RESET_ALL)
      t.sleep(2)
      os.system('clear')
      fries_order()
  else:
    os.system('clear')
    print(Fore.RED+"That is a invalid entry please try again.")
    print(Style.RESET_ALL)
    t.sleep(2)
    os.system('clear')
    fries_order()
  os.system('clear')
  str_money=str(money)
  print("You ordered a",choice[0],"sandwich.")
  print("You ordered a",choice[1],"drink.")
  print("You ordered a",choice[2],"fry.")
  print("Your cost so far is: $"+str_money)
```

I have tried to make the main_choice varible global, but to no avail.

Comment: `main_choice=input("-").lower` => `main_choice=input("-").lower()`

Comment: Voting to close as a typo, since `lower` is called correctly in other places.

Comment: You have no functions, so *all* variables are global already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't calling `lower()` in

```
main_choice=input("-").lower
```

so `main_choice` is not a string but the bound function `lower`:

```
>>> main_choice=input("-").lower
-foo
>>> main_choice
<built-in method lower of str object at 0x106bebeb0>
>>> main_choice == "foo"
False
>>>
```

– you'll need

```
main_choice = input("-").lower()
```

to call `lower()` and have it return the lower-cased string for you to assign.

```
>>> main_choice=input("-").lower()
-foo
>>> main_choice
'foo'
>>> main_choice == "foo"
True
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll mark your answer in a bit.